# Create new object on ModelForm save, with values from related model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a ModelForm to allow the creation of new User objects via a subclass of CreateView, and I also have a UserProfile model with a "client" field, and connected to the User model.
This:

```py
# models.py
class UserProfile(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)


# forms.py
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    def create_userprofile(self, user, client):
        profile = UserProfile()
        profile.user = user
        profile.client = client
        profile.save()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'groups')


# views.py
class UserCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'usermanager/user_form.html'
    form_class = UserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('usermanager:list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ### Make sure a newly created user has a UserProfile.

        # some pseudo-code thrown in

        # First save the user
        result = super(UserCreate, self).form_valid(form)

        # Now that we have a user, let's create the UserProfile
        form.create_userprofile(created_user, current_user.userprofile.client)

        # Finally return the result of the parent method.
        return result
```

I want to be able to create a new UserProfile when the form is submitted (and is valid, of course), so I was doing it on the CreateView.form_valid() method, but I need the ID of the just created user, which at that time I don't think I have - do I?

At the same time, I need to assign to the new UserProfile the same client as the current (not the new) user has in his profile.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try checking if

```
self.object.pk
```

has what you want after calling

```
super(UserCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

in your form_valid method.